# How can convert a arraybuffer response type to string in python?

Tags: javascript, python, request, arraybuffer

I have API server where response to any requests with   `arraybuffer` format.
This API web server Works properly in Java script as shown as:

```
xhrOverride.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request = $.ajax({
url: url,
method: 'GET'
        .
        .
        .

request .done(function(data) {
                mydata = {
                    buffer: data,
                };
                myconverter(mydata );
            }
                .
                .
                .


function myconverter(data) {
    const buffer = data.buffer;
    let vals = new Uint32Array(data.buffer, 0, 5);
    data.n = vals[0] / 1000 + vals[1] ;
    let stride = vals[2];
    data.x= vals[3];
    let limits = new Int16Array(buffer, 20, 4);
    data.city= limits[0];
    data.united= limits[1];
    data.vil= limits[2];
  .
  .
  .
```

Above code Works properly in Java Script, But does not work in Python as shown as:

```
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
```

Output:

```
��7DT�z !��?���{_s:x�0�Ɗ���$����Fp�@�Uk�K�u�jq,���k�,v��Z�j�...
```

I convert response  to base64 then  base64  to UTF-8  but again my answer is :

```
��7DT�z !��?���{_s:x�0�Ɗ���$����Fp�@�Uk�K�u�jq,���k�,v��Z�j�...
```

How can I convert response to real string?

Answer (score 0):

Consider sending/parsing `ArrayBuffer` as strings.  Here's the JS util, and perhaps a similar one in Python would suffice?

```
class ArrayBufferUtil {
  static toString(buffer) {
    return new Uint8Array(buffer).toString()
  }
  
  static parse(s) {
    return new Uint8Array(
      s.split(',').map(i => parseInt(i, 10))
    ).buffer
  }
}
```

Comment: this structures  not exist in python